# Prevent view from scrolling to navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c

At one of my view controllers I have behavior that I needed, at another one - not. "Correct" view controller's content doesn't overlap a status bar (20 points bar at top). For the second one I have another layout. Please take a look.

Correct layout:

[image]

Wrong:

[image]

Why is that happen and how could i fix it?

Comment: check ur scrollview y frame

Comment: That is actually a table view.

Comment: then set your tableview frame (x:0, y: 20, width, height)

Comment: @ShangariC okay that will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Auto-Layout - check your topmost constraint. 
It should define a relation between **Top Layout Guide** and your desired **View**, but not between your View and Superview.Top

And, of course, there shouldn't be any hardcoded frames or constants.

Something like this:

[image]